# On the relativistic contraction of orbitals

Tags: orbitals, atoms, relativistic

In Platinum $\text{Pt}$, why do $\text{s}$ and $\text{p}$ orbitals contract when electrons start travelling at relativistic speeds $|v|\sim c$, while $\text{d}$ orbital expands?

The way I reasoned about this is that due to relativistic effects, relativistic mass of an electron increases:

$$|v|\sim c\rightarrow m_c = \frac{m_{0}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\uparrow$$

Which means that they possess higher kinetic energy and Bohr radius shrinks. However, due to  $\text{d}$ orbital suffering from shielding effect, it expands while $\text{s}$ and $\text{p}$ orbitals contract in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $d$ and $f$ orbitals do not expand due to the speed (or more accurately, the ratio of energy drawn from the electrostatic field to the rest mass-energy) of the innermost electrons in those orbitals ($3d,4f$). They expand because the shielding effect changes.

In the case of $s$ orbitals, only for the innermost $1s$ subshell do the electrons actually draw an amount of energy from the electrostatic field that's comparable with the rest-mass energy. That orbital then contracts relativistically. But now the $2s$ orbital, seeking the lowest spherically symmetric state orthogonal to the $1s$ orbital, shrinks in response even though the relativistic effect is smaller. This indirect effect cascades to all the $s$ orbitals as they respectively seek the lowest available orthogonal spherically symmetric states.

This cascading shrinkage is greatly diminished for $p$ and higher angular momentum orbitals because their wavefunctions have nodes passing through the nucleus and thus much less probability density in the strongly electrostatically-attracted region. Instead the shrunken $s$ orbitals now shield the higher-angular-momentum orbitals more effectively, causing the latter orbitals to expand under the decreased unshielded nuclear charge. The net expansion is greatest for $d,f,$ etc. orbitals because their multiple nodes through the nucleus decreases the probability of hitting the strongly attracted region more than is the case for $p$ orbitals.

The net result of all this is that for the heaviest elements, the "inert pair" effect is accompanied by a "reverse inert pair" effect in which higher-angular-momentum electrons are activated.